# Проверка занятости логина + jquery

Tags: jquery

Вы тащил через запрос значение 1 то есть означает что данный Логин есть, как через $.post он же ajax запрос проверить что если 1 то Логин занят, если 1 не равен 0 то Логин уже занят загвоздка именно со стороны jquery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'xxx',
    data: mata,
    success: function(data) {
        //допустим что тебе в ответ пришла единица, т.е. data == 1
        if (data == 1) {
            alert('ЛОГИН ЗАНЯТ');
        }
    }
});
```

Пожалуйста, читайте ваш вопрос перед тем как его опубликовать. Попробуйте сами осмыслить речевую конструкцию, уважайте других людей.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но что то. С кодом выше не получается, вы можете подробнее его объяснить?

Comment: url - надеюсь, заменили на свой;

mata - ваши входные данные;

Что выводит у вас data в success функции?

Comment: Спасибо всем, частично сам решил проблему, а так действительно но своё значение request подставлять вместо "mata" что выше